# Display phone number of subscriber in SMS with AMPScript and MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

I am actually using Marketing Cloud MobileConnect feature in order to make personalization on SMS campaigns. And i would like to print the mobile number of my customer using AMPScript inside an SMS. 
Do you think that this piece of code is going to work ?

```
SET @mn = MOBILE_NUMBER
v(@mn)
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
%%[
var @mn
set @mn = AttributeValue("MOBILE_NUMBER") 
]%%
%%[ if not empty(@mn) then ]%%
  Your mobile number is: %%=v(@mn)=%%
%%[ else ]%%
  Mobile number not found.
%%[ endif ]%%
```

**Reference**

- [AMPScript Syntax Guide](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/)
- [AMPScript Functions](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#alphalist)